# How are "How about you?"/"What about you?" different in meaning in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

How are "How about you?"/"What about you?" different in meaning in this context?

> Morning, Mike.
> Oh, hi there, Jane. What's up?
> Nothing much. I'm just taking these back to the library. **How/What** about you?
> Oh, you know. Same old thing.

Comment: They are not different in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

*“How about you”* should be used when **asking for a more specific intention or means** from the person you’re talking to.

*“What about you”* should be used when **asking for a general statement** about you.

Both are interchangeable, but “how” is generally more specific.

### How about you?

We use *“how about you”* in a more friendly manner because we usually want to get to know what a person is up to. Often, we’ll ask someone we’re interested in getting to join us for something.

For example:

> I'm going to the cinema tonight. **How about you?**

In this example, I am saying that I'm going to the cinema tonight, and asking "How about you?", is kind of like **inviting** the person to go with me (to the cinema).

### What about you?

*“What about you”* means you’re asking someone for general information about themselves. We are actually interested in that person.

For example:

> I'm going to the cinema tonight. **What about you?**

In this example, I'm not asking you to join me to the cinema. Instead, I'm actually curious and want to know about your plans tonight.

Ok, let's look at another example:

> I'm meeting John tomorrow. How about you?

It's like saying: "I'm meeting John tomorrow, would you like to join me?" or "I'm meeting John tomorrow, why don't you come with me?"

> I'm meeting John tomorrow. What about you?

I am meeting John tomorrow, but you are not invited to join me, and I don't want you to come with me. I'm curious what will you be doing tomorrow, and asking for that.

So yes, there **is** a difference between "How" and "What", but as the difference is so subtle, most of the speakers don't know, or maybe I should say they just don't care, like me.

##### Attributions:

https://grammarhow.com/how-about-you-vs-what-about-you/